# What would be a minimal way to create a safe default file name in Bash?

Tags: bash, filenames, overwrite

I want to have a Bash function define a safe default file name for an output file. So, with an input file name such as `myFile.txt` specified, the *default* file name for the output file could be something such as `myFile_1.txt` or `myFile_2.txt` if `myFile_1.txt` exists in the working directory (i.e., an incremented integer is appended as necessary in order to avoid overwriting existing files).

Here is some example code that exhibits the behaviour:

```
if [ "${fileName2}" == "" ]; then
    count=1
    fileName2="${fileName1%.*}_${count}.${fileName1##*.}"
    while [ -e "${fileName2}" ]; do
        let count=${count}+1
        fileName2="${fileName1%.*}_${count}.${fileName1##*.}"
    done
fi
echo "${fileName2}"
```

What would be some minimal way to have this type of behaviour?

Comment: I am looking for a *minimal* way of doing this type of naming.

Comment: So you want a [code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Oooh, I didn't know of this. It looks fun! I'm really just trying to make this type of procedure minimal and standard because it is to be added to a bunch of functions that can't have dependencies on other functions (or non-standard Linux programs).

Comment: What's not minimal about it? Doesn't use a single external program, it's pure bash. Stick it in a function and reuse everywhere.

Comment: What you are doing is vulnerable against race conditions. If process A went off from CPU, right after the evaluation of the `if` statement, a second process might enter the CPU and create the file. You should use `tempfile` for that